# Is this an odd behaviour of Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a void function `x2y` that updates `x` to `y` through their addresses.

The `Rcpp` code is like this

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <iostream>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
void x2y(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x,
         Rcpp::NumericVector& y)
{
  y = 1.0 / (1.0 + Rcpp::exp(-x));

  std::cout << "output(0)= " << y(0) << std::endl;
}
```

If `y` is initialized with `NA`s it is not updated:

```
x <- c(-1, 0, 2)

y <- c(NA, NA, NA)
x2y(x, y)
print(y)
[1] NA NA NA
```

But if

```
y <- c(NaN, NaN, NaN)
x2y(x, y)
print(y)
[1] 0.2689414 0.5000000 0.8807971
```

or if

```
y <- c(-99, -99, -99)
x2y(x, y)
print(y)
[1] 0.2689414 0.5000000 0.8807971
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: This has been discussed a million times, look eg for references to 'Rcpp proxy model'.  The (sole !!) interface we have to R is pointer based.